# find the centroid of shown plane figure

Tags: calculus

[image]

---

Here is what I have so far
equation of top curve : $f(x) = -\frac{4}{4.5^2}x^2 + 4$
equation of circle :  $g(x) = \sqrt{1.8^2 - x^2}$

By symmetry, $\overline{x} = 0$

How do I go about finding $\overline{y}$ ?
Can [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/CenterOfMass_files/eq0006M.gif) formula still be used for composite shapes ?

Comment: I have also worked the area of green region :  $24 - \frac{1.8^2 \pi}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential ingredient for this problem is the *moment equation*, which says the following: When $(0,\bar y)$ is the centroid of the green area $A$ then
$$\bar y\cdot{\rm area}(A)=\int_P y\ {\rm d}(x,y)-\int_H y\ {\rm d}(x,y)\ ,$$
where
$$P:=\{(x,y)\>|\>0\leq y\leq f(x), \ -4.5\leq x\leq 4.5\},\quad H:=\{(x,y)\>|\>0\leq y\leq g(x), \ -1.8\leq x\leq 1.8\}\ .$$
Therefore one has to compute
$$\int_P y\ {\rm d}(x,y)=\int_{-4.5}^{4.5}\int_0^{f(x)} y\ dy\ \ dx={1\over2}\int_{-4.5}^{4.5} f^2(x)\ dx=\ldots\ ,$$
and similarly for $\int_H y\ {\rm d}(x,y)$. At the end solve for $\bar y$.